# Scala: return from Runnable

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, runnable

I am learning Scala. I am reading a Scala program:

```
class MyProg() extends StrictLogging with Runnable {
  private val scheduledFuture = new AtomicReference[ScheduledFuture[_]]
  def start() = {
    scheduledFuture.set(executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, initialDelaySeconds, intervalSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
  }

  def stop() = {
    Option(scheduledFuture.get()).map(_.cancel(true))
  }

  override def run() = try {
    process()
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => logger.warn("Error", e)
  }

  def process() :Unit {
    // do something
    if (condition) return // Line 203
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Another piece of code to start the `Runnable`:

```
Option(myProg).map(_.start)
```

My questions:

1, it is right to return from inside a `Runnable`? `process()` is scheduled to run every `intervalSeconds` seconds. even sometimes `process()` return from inside, it still will be called `intervalSeconds` seconds later. Am I right?

2, Can we use `System.exit(0)` or `throw new Exception("...")` here? After `System.exit(0)` or `throw new Exception("...")` called, `process()` will be called **again**?

3, by the way, why `def process() :Unit {}`? can we use `def process() :Unit = {}`

Any comments welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the `return` is from the `process` function, it isn't the most scala idiomatic way, but it is fine doing it, and sometimes it's improve performances/readability.
   [scheduleWithFixedDelay](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) delay is between termination of one execution and the commencement of the next.
2. System.exit(0) will terminate the jvm, so nothing will run after that.
   for throwing exception is depends: if exception is thrown inside the `process` function then it will rerun. The scheduler is actually run the `run` function, which catch all the exceptions thrown from `process`.
3. `def process() :Unit {}` is deprecated and should not be used. always use the 
   `def process() :Unit = {}` way.

This code seems to be converted from java, and I dont think it good starting point to learn scala.
Any way, the best way to learn is to try. Spend some time to 'play' with it a bit.